# Why does class member inline initialisation not work when exported in c++ module?

Tags: visual-c++-2015, c++-modules

I've just started playing with the experimental modules in c++ in visual studio 2015 and found a difference in behaviour between a class exported in a module and a 'normal' class when using inline initialization.

```
module FooMod;
export class Foo
{
    int m_num = 34;
    public:
        int getNum() const
        {
            return m_num;
        }
};
```

My consuming code:

```
#include <iostream>
class Bar
{
    int m_num = 56;

public:
    int getNum() const 
    {
       return m_num;
    } 
};

import FooMod;

int main()
{

    Foo foo;
    std::cout << "foo num = " << foo.getNum() << std::endl;

    Bar bar;
    std::cout << "bar num = " << bar.getNum() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo num = 12125207  or some other random number.
bar num = 56
```

If I supply an empty constructor for Foo ie Foo(){} then the above code works as expected and I get foo num = 34. (Incidentally Foo() = default; does not work as I get unresolved symbol errors.)

Can anyone explain what is going on? Is it a bug or am I missing something to do with the way modules work?